# ".am.in" ? Is it okay to write ".in" without generating it?

Tags: autotools

Simply put, I ran upon a "buildconf.py.am.in" file inside the project we're developing at work. Not really expert in autotools (I had to learn them for this job), this seems quite strange to me. Inside there's two `VAR=@VAR@` and two `VAR=[@]VAR[@]`.

How could there be an ".am.in" ? To me, this means that we write an .in to generates a .am that will be used to generate another .in (or .py, maybe). Does it look "legit" or should it be "fixed" ? Thus after the `configure` step, I do have a "buildconf.py.am", which is used during `make` process to generate a .py. It contains the following:

```
do_subst = sed  -e 's,\[@\]APP_VARDIR\[@\],$(localstatedir)/app/,g' \
    -e 's,\[@\]APP_LOGDIR\[@\],$(logdir),g'

buildconf.py: buildconf.py.am
    $(do_subst) < $(srcdir)/buildconf.py.am > buildconf.py
```

Is that "normal" or "acceptable" ? As I'm trying to consolidate the whole thing, since everything's become "tricky" and difficult to update, it looks like it's one of the huge amounts of fixes to me.

TY !

EDIT:

The script mostly defines paths for folders used by "plugins", thus needing things such as the datadir or the soft installdir. It also defines the folder structure to be used by those plugins so that they can be imported by the python code of the so-called plugins. Besides, those "plugins" actually are the server/routing layer of the application.

- the `buildconf.py.am.in` file is not generated, but written by hand;
- `buildconf.py.am` is declared amongst others in `AC_CONFIG_FILES` (how could it be ? It's supposed to tell "there must be a `buildconf.py.am.in.am` next to it, which will be used to generate a `buildconf.py.am.in.in` to then make a "`buildoncf.py.am.in` file... But all we want and get is `buildconf.py`);
- running `configure` generates `buildconf.py.am`, setted variables are two booleans which tells if the mongoDB and web UI plugins are provided  ;
- `make` generates the final `buildconf.py`, to be imported where the constants it holds are needed. It is done at this time since it needs -I guess- variables expanded during the configure step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may just be a naming problem.

*Usually* `.am` files are included by `Makefile.am` and are expanded by `automake`, so for instance they are used to have per-directory definition of sources and targets while keeping the overall build non-recursive.

You *can* include files at the `Makefile` level so that the inclusion is executed by `make` instead, but calling them `.am` sounds wrong that way.

But in this case it's neither of those, this should probably rather be called `.in.in` (there are a few scripts that do something like that), but it feels a bit over the top. It probably makes just about the same amount of sense to do the processing once, by just applying all replacements during `make` phase.

I guess the likeliest case is is that somehow the original expansion was incorrect and it stratified, but not knowing the codebase it's hard to tell.

Comment: Firstly, thank you. May it simply be that the developer misunderstood ".in" and ".am" roles and autotools good practice or something. Because autotools have been imposed by "a genius coworker" (those who know who's a good developer, who's a bad one...).

That's why I am kinda lost: I am a huge noob in the autotools field, but feels like "our expert" already is behind me in terms of autotools knowledge, which is absolutely awkward to me. No matter what, the important part is that this is clarified so I can be sure I'm not doing things the bad way... :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a three-step custom template like e.g. in Unity mono.
There template first gets processed by `autogen.sh`: `.am.in` -> `.am`, then by automake `.am` -> `.in` and finally by `configure` script `Makefile.in` -> `Makefile`.

In `autogen.sh` it's:

```
if test x$has_ext_mod = xtrue; then
       cat mono/mini/Makefile.am.in ../mono-extensions/mono/mini/Makefile.am > mono/mini/Makefile.am
else
       cat mono/mini/Makefile.am.in > mono/mini/Makefile.am
fi
```